# Insert empty line after the contents of a file in a new file

Tags: linux, blank-line

This is a simple problem, I'm just stuck on it. I am taking the contents of a bunch of different files and printing each file's name as a header before its contents. That much works. But I want to have an empty line separating the the contents of one file and the header for the next file's content.

I want it to look like:

> File 1 header
>
> File 1 contents
>
> [empty space]
>
> File 2 header
>
> File 2 contents

I tried putting \n after "{}" in my code, but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
find . -type f -name '*_top_hits.txt' -print -exec cat {} \; > combinedresults.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just an empty `echo` as part of the `find` `-exec` as

```
find . -type f -name "*_top_hits.txt" -print -exec sh -c "cat {};echo"  \; > combinedresults.txt
```

The `echo` just produces a single empty new-line after each file content. Also you don't need multiple `-exec` options rather use a single sub-shell.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain sh -c?

Comment: @lynkyra: It is invoking a shell explicitly to run those commands, it necessarily need not be `sh`, can also be `bash -c`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a second `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -name '*_top_hits.txt' -print -exec cat {} \; -exec echo \; > combinedresults.txt
```

One side effect of this is that a new line will be added at the end after the contents of the last file.